# How to use Sybase cursor in Java?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a `Sybase` procedure returning nothing. Now I want to modify the procedure and wanted an `OUT` parameter similar to `SYS_REFCURSOR` in Oracle to get the result of a query. Can you please suggest ?

Code:

```
create procedure get_rec_test
        @buss_date datetime
as
begin                         
        INSERT INTO TEST 
        SELECT *  FROM  short_positions_report    

end
GO
```

In the above code how to add the out parameter to get resultset from `TEST` table. ? Am a novice in sybase and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which engine is that? ASE? or IQ? What version? Please post result of "select @@version" statement.

Comment: It's ASE and result of this query is `Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 26397 SMP SP138 /P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase157sp138x/4002/64-bit/FBO/Mon Aug 29 20:46:15 2016`

Comment: What is the client? If it is Java then this query will return a resultset. Another way is to populate a temporary table created outside of the procedure. If this question is not about IQ please remove the tag.